# Test exist javascript widget or not

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

How I can easy test in cucumber with capybara, exist widget on page or not?

Comment: tag whether the script exists that calls the widget? or that the widget is functioning / loading?

Comment: That the javascript simply present on the page and I can find new DOM elements, which this script created

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the widget with the script src being local, then just mark the cucumber feature with

`@javascript`

And it will evaluate javascript for you.

If you're loading a widget from another site, then this method won't work (and you'll need to look at Selenium or similar)

Comment: Can I load selenium driver once, for selected feature?